# Merge cells into array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, merge

I want to calculate this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N1:Q1;{L6;M6;O6;P6})
```

This is possible if {L6;M6;O6;P6} is an array.
I've tried with this formula, but it is not working.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N1:Q1;CHOOSE({1;2;3;4};L6;M6;O6;P6))
```

It is not possible to change the structure of tables.
Is there some workaround without using VBA?

Thank you for quick response!

Comment: You should be able to make this formula work as an array formula (pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` instead of just `Enter` when you enter the formula into a cell). Yet, the fact that the second array consists of non-adjacent cells might throw the formula off. Would it be possible to make the second array adjacent like `L6:O6` or `M6:P6`?

Comment: No, it is not possible to make them adjacent without changing the structure of the table. I've tried pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter and it is not working, none of the obove mentioned formulas.

Comment: Since these are merely two times four cells I'd rather write out the sumproduct as four multiplications and then sum them up. That seems much easier than a VBA-based solution. Yet, if you really wanna go with VBA then I'd expect your preliminary VBA code to achieve just that. After all, this website is not a free code-writing service. Instead we'd like to help programmers (and aspirants) with **their** code. The added difficulty with VBA is probably to make it dynamic and allow for any combination of n-elements in any array (and how you want to divide them into two sets).

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?  The second formula seems to work here.  Perhaps you need to replace the semicolons with commas to produce the horizontal orientation of the array within your array constant (eg: `{1,2,3,4}`).

Comment: I get as result #VALUE!. I've tried repacing with commas, but the formula requires semicolons. So, basic question would be to how to create array from cells...

Comment: Choose formula takes specific numbers from some array. i.e. =SUM(CHOOSE({1;2;3;4};L6;M6;O6;P6)) is equal to =SUM(L6;M6;O6;P6). I thought that it returns an array, but it doesn't. It returns only first item from the array.